# How to initiate a callback in script tag inside a vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, frontend, ecmascript-5

this is my script tag inside my index.html.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourKey&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

How can I get initMap callback inside one of my vue.js components?

Comment: why aren't you just using npm packages for this? example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps

Comment: I want to know how to make this happen without a package!